# Java - find indexof for part of a needle in array haystack

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

I am trying to find what array index position contains part of a string.

```
FullDirPrt = "a1a" "b2b" "c3c"

String doT ="b2";
int DotPos = Arrays.asList(FullDirPrt).indexOf(doT);
```

If I search for b2b it returns indexOf. If I search for only b2, it returns -1.

Comment: jmort's answer does give the position, the other two are good for doing something when it is found. thx for the quick respnses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check each item in the array individually, as each array item is a separate string:

```
String[] full = { "a1a", "b2b", "c3c" };
String doT = "b2";

for(int i = 0; i < full.length; i++) {
    if(full[i].contains(doT)) {
        System.out.println("Found item at index " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx jmort, that hit the spot!

Answer (score 0):

You are matching on the entire string, you are going to have to loop through the whole list or array, and then check each indexOf on each of those strings.

```
for (String s : FullDirPrt) {
    if (s.indexOf("bs") > 0) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Simple String array without using List also you can do like below.

```
String[] full={"a1a", "b2b", "c3c"};
String doT = "b2";
for(String str:full){
if(str.contains(doT)){
System.out.println(str+" contains "+doT);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int stringFinder(String haystack, String needle) {
    return haystack.indexOf(needle);       
}
```

> haystack is String
> needle which is to find in It

```
string.indexOf(stringTofind)
```